# Cloud based database solution

Tags: spatial-database, database, mysql, database-design, cloud-gis

I'm looking for a cloud based database solution where I can store about 1 GB worth of tabular data and both myself and my client can access to perform SQL queries.  I'm looking for this database to have a simple Graphic User Interface that's intuitive to allow custom queries and to export results in a format such as CSV, DBF, etc. I'm okay with a monthly charge less than $50 per month.

I've looked at Amazon Web Services RDS, but I'm really confused how to "share" a MySQL database with my client. My understanding is that AWS RDS is a cloud based database solution where multiple users can access and manipulate data.  It's sounding more like a database has to be installed on your local machine and a connection is then made.  I'm not looking to download database software (ie MySQL), I just need the database and connections all to be in the cloud.

Comment: A Webserver with MySQL would be fine (with some security) Amazon RDS for MySQL DB Instances are cloudbased you just need to load your own data into them. https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/

Comment: You can access data via REST/CHAP Service (RDS) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html & http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.VersionMgmt

Comment: Thanks Mapperz!  According to AMW, “You can simply launch a MySQL Instance and connect your application within minutes without additional configuration.” I was able to make a ‘MySQL Instance’, then I realized that I would need to install the MySQL software on my local computer then establish a connection to AWS.  Is there a way to not have a MySQL database on my local computer and just have everything (software and hosting) provided by AWS?  I wouldn’t want my client to have to download MySQL and establish a connection in order for both of us to access the database.

Comment: You need some client for communicating with MySQL. There are loads to select from and you do not need to install another MySQL database engine on your computer. But some client you do need. There are also web based clients.

Comment: I think the only SE site that this would not be too broad, and be on-topic,  for is [softwarerecs.se] but make sure that you review their help before making any post their because they are quite strict on how questions should be structured in order to become answerable there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want by standing up a database service using Amazon RDS, and then installing a web-accessible database management on another system.  This would permit you and your client to make queries against the database without requiring any software installation on your local computer.

If you are familiar with EC2 and basic system administration, you could install [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) on an EC2 instance.  phpMyadmin provides a complete MySQL management interface, including the ability to execute SQL queries and download the results in a variety of formats.  I would not necessarily call the UI "intuitive", but it is functional.

As an alternative to installing this into an EC2 instance, you could utilize a PaaS service like [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/), which is in general (a) much simpler for this sort of single-application use, and (b) free, because this use will fall easily within the free tier, which permits you to create three applications.

Getting phpMyAdmin running in OpenShift is very simple, but probably beyond the scope of this answer.

There are other web-based MySQL administration tools available.  I looked briefly at [sqlbuddy](http://sqlbuddy.com/), which has a much simpler interface but does not appear to offer the ability to download queries as CSV.  It is able to export entire tables that way.

Comment: Thanks so much larsks! I'm very new to this, so please bare with me.  I have an existing Instance with AWS RDS.  If I get phpMyAdmin running in OpenShift, then I somehow make the 'connection' between the two in AWS?

Comment: Yes.  Your RDS instance has a hostname, listed as the "endpoint" for the RDS instance and having a name like "mydatabase.chmidcv5ugmr.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com".  You would configure this into your web application.  You may need to ensure you have your security groups appropriately configured to permit access to the RDS instance.